# Need to get clarification from a user who answered a question

Tags: discussion

How can I get clarification on an answer (by Vytautas Butkus) from either him or the community for the post "jQuery Hide and show Toggle div with Plus and Minus Icon?" (at [jQuery hide and show toggle div with plus and minus icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186565/jquery-hide-and-show-toggle-div-with-plus-and-minus-icon)) but everywhere I look it says I can't ask a question (must provide an answer). I'm dead in the water right now, so how can I get my question to that user or the community? Thanks.

Comment: Leave a comment against the post asking for clarification.

Comment: @JonW: He can't low rep.

Comment: If you can't post a comment, ask a question, and link the original answer

Comment: OK, answer one question on SO and get a single upvote so you have 10 rep, then leave a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @JonW 50 points are needed to comment

Comment: Ah yes, thought they were part of new user restrictions, but my bad, they're a separate privilege.

Comment: Not sure why a newbie can't leave a comment. I'll never get the 50 points required for that. Seems like Jan's suggestion is the only way. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @JYN - It means spammers can't use comments to spam.

Comment: @JYN. Getting 50 points isn't actually particularly difficult. I wouldn't call myself a great programmer, and I have over 2,000. I'm also an atheist with over 1,000 points on [Christianity Stack Exchange](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/). *shrug*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep that answer on hold, ask a few (good) questions, answer a few, get 50 reputation points, and then you'll be able to leave a comment on it.

Answer (score 8):

Ask some questions, answer some questions. [Suggest some good edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on existing posts.

With these, you will get reputation.

When you have enough reputation, you will be able to [add comments](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Or you may suggest some good edits.

Comment: @hims056 - Ta. Forgot about those.